# My PDO result doesn't work for displaying

Tags: php, object, pdo

I test a tuto. i'm novice in php.
I have a entity in news.php, a manager and a page for displaying results.
I execute a query with PDO. i have  results but ican't display them.

the entity is like that:

```
class News {

     private $_id;
     private $_titre;
     private $_contenu;

     public function id()
     {
         return $this->_id;
     }


     public function titre()
     {
         return $this->_titre;
     }


     public function contenu()
     {
         return $this->_contenu;
     }



     public function setId($id)
     {
         if(!is_int($id))
             throw new Exception('L\'id n\'es pas de type int');

         $this->_id = $id;
     }


     public function setTitre($titre)
     {
         if(!is_string($titre))
             throw new Exception('Le titre n\'es pas de type string');

             $this->_titre = $titre;
     }


     public function setContenu($contenu)
     {
         if(!is_string($contenu))
             throw new Exception('Le contenu n\'es pas de type string');

          $this->_contenu = $contenu;
     }


 }
```

My news manager :

```
class newsManager
 {
   private $_db;
 const SELECT_5LAST_NEWS  = 'SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,5';

 public function select5News()
     {
         $query =  $this->_db->query(self::SELECT_5LAST_NEWS);
         $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'News');
         return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'News');;
     }

 }
```

Then i test my view:

```
require 'classes/newsManager.php';

$newsmngr = new newsManager(); $req = $newsmngr->select5News();

foreach ($req as $u) {
   print_r($u); }
```

thats give:

```
News Object ( [_id:News:private] => [_titre:News:private] =>
[_auteur:News:private] => [_contenu:News:private] =>
[_dateAjout:News:private] => [_dateModif:News:private] => [id] => 3
[auteur] => howsDoingThis [titre] => where i am.... [contenu] => Lorem
ipsum dolor sit amet,(...)
```

my result is filled but when i try to display it nothing happens with that code:

```
foreach($req  as $news)
 {
     echo '<section><p class="titre"><a href="administration.php?id='.$news-id().'">'.$news->titre().'</a></p>';
     echo '<p class="description">'.$news->contenu().'</p></section>';
 }
```

anyone can help me plz. thanks

Comment: `$news-id()` to `$news->id()`

Comment: Thanks.I just see that but it's not the matter. i don't know how i can manipulate my resultset:

Comment: i obtain this:$req = $newsmngr->select5News();

Comment: it's filled by objects but i don't know how displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

id and contenu are private variable, you can't access them directly. You must use some public getter methods defined in your News class

```
public function getId(){
    return $this->_id;
}
```

Then you get the data through the getter method like this `$news->getId();`

Hope this help

Comment: in my class, i already have a public get method :
 public function id()
     {
         return $this->_id;
     }

Comment: I solve my problem by calling $news->titre instead of the method of my object $news->getTitre()